# how to allow user download file over web page on window server 2003

Tags: asp.net

I have a webpage deployment on iis6, window server 2003, and i want to allow user can download some file from webpage
I store this file on the backup folder. I added NETWORK SERVICE user to the folder but I still can not download this file

Simple, i have a file and i want user can download this by link: http://www.aitapgdtrh.edu/Backup/SaoLuu13112012_1435.bak

it's shown the error:
The page cannot be found

HTTP Error 404 - File or directory not found.
Internet Information Services (IIS)

Please help me config to download it, Thanks!

Comment: How are you trying to download the file?  What kind of error message are you getting?

Comment: my file is stored at backup folder

Comment: i use the url: www.aitapgdtrh.edu/Backup/SaoLuu13112012_1435.bak

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer for my question:
It's:

Open IIS, right click, choose Properties.
At group MIME type, click News,

Add:

Extension: .bak

MIME type: data/sql

then it's ok :)

Answer (score 1):

HTTP 404 means that IIS cannot find the file specified by `/Backup/SaoLuu13112012_1435.bak`.  I assume this is because it's located at `C:\Backup` and not in `inetpub`.

Request URLs are relative to the website root path, so `/Backup/SaoLuu13112012_1435.bak` will refer to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aitapgdtrh.edu\Backup\SaoLuu13112012_1435.bak` *not* `C:\Backup\SaoLuu13112012_1435.bak`.

You can reference locations outside of your website root path by using a [virtual directory](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/windowsserver2003/library/iis/5adfcce1-030d-45b8-997c-bdbfa08ea459.mspx)<sup>1</sup>:

1. Open IIS
2. Browse to your website
3. Right click the root node
4. Click "New Virtual Directory"
5. Specify "Backup" as the Alias
6. Specify "C:\Backup" as Path
7. Assign **read permissions only**
8. Save the directory

<sup>1</sup>You're allowing read access to the entire `Backup` directory to anonymous clients by doing this.  For security, you may want to require authentication (either NTLM or Forms).

Comment: thank you, the real path is:"C:\Inetpub\vhosts\aitapgdtrh.edu\httpdocs\admin\Backup". I try create another virtual directory follow you and assign "Directory browsing". The link: "aitapgdtrh.edu/Backupnew" listed my backup file. But when i click to download file so the same error shown: "HTTP Error 404 - File or directory not found" ^_^

Comment: So, what need i do to download it? Thank you so much :)

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is just write an ASP.Net script that uses System.Web.UI.WebControls FileUpload:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx

Comment: Thanks but It's not the way i want. Simple, i have a file and i want user can download this by link: http://aitapgdtrh.edu/Backup/SaoLuu13112012_1435.bak

Comment: Thank you for your edit: you should have mentioned the "404" in your original post :)  ANYWAY - like just.another.programmer said: simply create a virtual directory in IIS, and make sure the web user has read permissions to the file.